# biblatex vs hyperref vs \appendix vs memoir

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, memoir

Here is an interesting one. In the example below, if the `book` class is used then the `\cite` in the second included document points to the bibliography generated for that page.

But when `memoir` is loaded it points to the previous file.

What gives?

**Update:**

It seems to be the definition of `\appendix`

Here is the `memoir` definition of the `\appendix` command

```
\renewcommand{\appendix}{\par
  \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \gdef\@chapapp{\appendixname}%
  \gdef\thechapter{\@Alph\c@chapter}%
 \anappendixtrue
}
```

The only difference compared to `book` is that last line

Here is an updated MWE

```
% \documentclass[a4paper]{book} % works
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir} % the citation on page 3 points to
                                % page 1
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname-refs.bib}
@article{test,
  author = "Test Testson",
  title = "Test",
  journal = "Some journal",
  year = 2020,
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname-a.tex}
\chapter{Test}
\cite{test}
\printbibliography[heading = subbibliography]
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname-b.tex}
\chapter{Test}
\cite{test}
\printbibliography[heading = subbibliography]
\end{filecontents}

\makeatletter
 % memoir definition of \appendix note the last line, remove and everything works
\renewcommand{\appendix}{\par
  \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \gdef\@chapapp{\appendixname}%
  \gdef\thechapter{\@Alph\c@chapter}%
  \anappendixtrue
}
\makeatother



\usepackage[
    backend = biber,
    refsection = chapter, % Chapter-wise bibliography
    citestyle = numeric,
    bibstyle = authoryear,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\addbibresource{\jobname-refs.bib}

\begin{document}

\include{\jobname-a}

\appendix


\include{\jobname-b}

\end{document}
```

Here is an image from the pdf

[image]

---

From Ulrikes analysis, this seems to be the proper solution added after loading `biblatex` (and reported to `biblatex`)

```
\makeatletter
\def\blx@refpatch@chapter@memoir#1{%
  \apptocmd\memchapinfo{#1}
    {}{\blx@err@patch{\string\memchapinfo}}%
  \apptocmd\memchapstarinfo{#1}
  {}{\blx@err@patch{\string\memchapstarinfo}}%
  \apptocmd\memappchapinfo{#1}
    {}{\blx@err@patch{\string\memchapinfo}}%
  \apptocmd\memappchapstarinfo{#1}
  {}{\blx@err@patch{\string\memchapstarinfo}}%
}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

biblatex hooks into memoir code to add a `\newrefsection` command when `refsection=chapter` is used. It adds is to `\memchapinfo`. When tracing the code one can see it:

```
\memchapinfo #1#2#3#4->\newrefsection 
#1<-\thechapter 
#2<-\f@rtoc 
#3<-\f@rhdr 
#4<-Test
```

But with `\anappendixtrue` `\memchapinfo` is not used but `\memappchapinfo` and so the `\newrefsection` is missing.

You could ask the biblatex maintainer to patch this command to. Alternatively you could a `\newrefsection` manually when starting the appendix.

Comment: Ahh, I would never have looked there. Thanks, I'll see if I can recommend a better solution.

Comment: Reported in https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1019 and hopefully fixed with https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/2e404bdfeff7212e9c801ea23e10a8476f6fe636.